# Add serde serialize/deserialize within macro_rules! in Rust

Tags: rust

I am working on a macro that computes the number of fields on a struct at runtime. I have an implementation whose source code is given below.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::Cell;

macro_rules! generate {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident : $t:ty),+}) => {
        struct $name { $($field: $t),+ }
        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                generate!(@count $($field),+)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $t1:tt, $($t:tt),+) => { 1 + generate!(@count $($t),+) };
    (@count $t:tt) => { 1 };
}

generate! { test1 { num: i32, s: Option<String> }}
generate! { test2 { num: i32, s: String }}

fn main() {
    let s = test1 { num: 0, s: None };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
    let s = test2 { num: 0, s: String::new() };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
}
```

The source code works fine except for the case when the struct is made serde Serializable or Deserializable. I am looking to add a rule inside macro_rules!{} such that it takes a directive like #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)] within 'generate', such that at compile time the macro allows me to count the number of fields as well as its serializable/deserializable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture attributes like `#[derive(...)]` using the `meta` fragment specifier. For example, a macro pattern to capture any number of attributes is:

```
$(#[$attr:meta])*
```

Which is then used in the output like so:

```
$(#[$attr])*
```

*Note that the `meta` specifier doesn't capture the `#[]` wrapper, so you have to write it explicitly in the pattern.*

This can be used to capture attributes on structs and struct fields, in this case transparently passing them through to the macro output. Here's a version of your macro that allows attributes on the struct and its fields ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9814e8323fd913ce93a0cd3332fca001)):

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

macro_rules! generate {
    (
        // Capture any number of attributes on the struct
        $(#[$attr:meta])*

        struct $name:ident {
            $(
                // Capture any number of attributes on each field
                $(#[$field_attr:meta])*
                $field:ident : $t:ty
            ),+

            $(,)?
        }
    ) => {
        // Emit the struct attributes
        $(#[$attr])*
        struct $name {
            $(
                // Emit the field attributes
                $(#[$field_attr])*
                $field: $t
            ),+
        }

        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                generate!(@count $($field),+)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $t1:tt, $($t:tt),+) => { 1 + generate!(@count $($t),+) };
    (@count $t:tt) => { 1 };
}

generate! {
    #[derive(Serialize)]
    struct Test1 {
        num: i32,
        #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
        s: Option<String>,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Test1 { num: 0, s: None };
    println!("Number of fields: {}", s.field_count());
    println!("Serialized: {}", serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap());
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Number of fields: 2
Serialized: {"num":0}
```

...showing that the `skip_serializing_if` field attribute was preserved.

Comment: As an additional benefit it also allows doc comments.